# Php method not being called

Tags: php, html, methods

I have been trying to debug this code for a while now, and it looks like the `build` method is not being called. I put echo's, var_dumps, and all other kinds of signs in it, but never get anything.

Full php code

```
class Auto_slideshow {

  private $_img_dir;

  //constructor sets directory containing the images
  function __construct($dir) {
    //Directory source from webroot
    $_img_dir = $dir;
  }

  //Iterates through directory and constructs HTML img list
  public function build() {

    //use SPL for directory iteration
    $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($_img_dir);

    $html = '';
    $i = 1;

    //Iterate through directory
    foreach ($iterator as $file) {

      //set a variable to add class of "show" on first element
      $showClass = $i === 1 ? ' class="show"' : null;

      //exclude '.' and '..' files
      if(!$iterator->isDot()) {

        //set src attribute for img tag
        $src = $_img_dir . $iterator->getFilename();

        //Grab sizes of images
        $size = getimagesize($_img_dir . $iterator->getFilename());
        var_dump($src);
        //create img tags
        $html .= '<img src="' . $src . '" ' . $size[3] . $displayNone . ' />' . "\r\n";

        $i++;
      }
    }

    return $html;
  } 
}
```

html call

```
<center>
    <div class="imagecontainer" id="auto-slideshow">
    <?php
    $show = new Auto_slideshow("../CMSC/images/master/slidestock/");
    $show->build();
    ?>
</div>
</center>
```

I also tried `print $show->build();`, as [the tutorial](http://daleconboy.com/portfolio/code/auto-slideshow) showed, which also did not work.

**Update**

I changed `$_img_dir` to `$this->$_img_dir' and called the method by`echo show->build();` and the method still isn't being called.

This is a matter of the method not even running, not even to the point of find the images yet.

**Update 2**

If I remove the entire php code within the html, the rest of the page loads just fine. As it is now, the html loads only to the div that contains the php then stop everything after it.

Comment: `$_img_dir` is not assigned to anything. You must use `$this->_img_dir` if you wish to assign values to class properties.

Comment: I think when you combine @jeroen 's and Kevins 's answer you will have a working solution if your img_dir exists ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix and update the code bellow:

Constructor:

> $this->_img_dir = $dir;

build Function:

> $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($this->_img_dir);
>
> $src = $this->_img_dir . $iterator->getFilename();
>
> $size = getimagesize($this->_img_dir . $iterator->getFilename());

You can call it:

> echo $show->build();

Comment: This crashes the page.

Comment: Never mind, I left out a $. But it still doesn't load any images.

Answer (score 3):

Have you used a `var_dump()` outside of the loop as well?

The problem is that your variable will remain NULL:

```
  //constructor sets directory containing the images
  function __construct($dir) {
    //Directory source from webroot

    // This is a local variable that will be gone when the constructor finishes:
    $_img_dir = $dir;
  }
```

You need:

```
  //constructor sets directory containing the images
  function __construct($dir) {
    //Directory source from webroot
    $this->_img_dir = $dir;
     ^^^^^^ here
  }
```

Comment: This breaks the page and nothing at all loads.

Comment: @CodyHarness Then you probably have a typo somewhere. And obviously you need to use the same variable `$this->_img_dir` in your other method as well.

Comment: I know the path is correct, I've tested that already. I did forget the add the `$this->` part, but after adding that it still breaks. It still should at least load the rest of the html above the php call, like it did before.

Comment: @CodyHarness I am not that familiar with the file iterator, but it seems you are using the wrong variable here: `$iterator->getFilename()`. Do you perhaps need `$file->getFilename()` and are you getting an exception now? You should enable error handling / display to see what breaks exactly.

Comment: Never mind, I forgot the $ on `this`, but it still doesn't load the images. I will give another iteration technique a shot.

Answer (score 3):

You return the text you want to display but you don't display it:

```
echo $show->build();
```